# Pairwise omission of NAs when running t.test on long format data

Tags: r, group-by, pivot, t-test

I am trying to run multiple t.tests by groups (0, 1, and 2), comparing "pre" and "post" data for various variables (biological tests). I have managed to get the data in long format df.

The problem here are NAs in the df. I do not want to remove the entire row using `na.omit`. I need this to be a `paired = TRUE` t.test, as "pre" and "post" data are from the same participants. When I run the above code below I get the error `` Caused by error in `complete.cases()`:! not all arguments have the same length ``.

code used:

````
library(tidyr)
library(broom)
df_pivot_long <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-group, names_to=c("test","stage"), names_sep="_") %>% 
  mutate(stage = factor(stage, levels=c("pre","post"))) %>% 
  group_by(group, test) %>% 
  summarize(tidy(t.test(value~stage, data=cur_data(), paired = TRUE, alternative = "two.sided", conf.level=0.99, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")))```
````

I tried using `tidy()`, but I can't coerce the function to ignore NAs pairwise. Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: Have you checked the `na.action` argument of `t.test()` function?